# Disable openapi spec validation in loopback

Tags: node.js, loopback4

I'm looking for a way to disable openapi spec validation in Loopback 4.

I'm still interested in keeping the swagger specs but I wish to replace the spec validation (body, params, query) with Joi. What I could achieve so far is validation from both loopback openapi validator and joi.

Since in my configuration, the joi schema provides the necessary metadata for the swagger specs and the validation specs by extending the base decorators.

My guess, is that I need to override something in the sequence, but I'm unable to find exactly what.